# run second mysqld instance for backup restore

Tags: linux, mysql, debian

I am trying to start a second mysqld instance to restore data from backup (innoDB).

Following the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-servers.html) I put together this:

```
P="/var/lib/reoback/backups/2014-06-30/var/lib/mysql"
cd $P
mkdir tmp
touch mysql.log
chown -R mysql:mysql .
# mysqld v5.0
mysqld --console --port=3399 --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --datadir=$P /
   --pid-file=$P/mysqld.pid --log=$P/mysql.log --log-bin=$P/bin.log /
   --log-error=$P/error.log --tmpdir=$P/tmp --innodb_force_recovery=6
```

and ended up crashing my running instance.

Question is: How do I create a second mysqld instance using the backup folder?

Comment: You need to look in the logs that the crashed instance wrote.

Comment: @Iain Well, it did not write any logs. I had some console output but I lost that while I restored the main instance. Can't try that again. That's why I am here to make it save this time.

Comment: `$P/error.log` ? And without logs we can only guess

Comment: @Iain no error.log and mysql.log is empty. I don't know why...

Answer (score 1):

Yes I would say you need a second socket. You can create one it using `mkfifo` - but maybe MySQL should recreate it on its own.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
P="/var/lib/reoback/backups/2014-06-30/var/lib/mysql"
chown -R mysql:mysql $P
# mysqld v5.0
mysqld --port=3399 --socket=$P/mysqld.sock --datadir=$P \
    --pid-file=$P/mysqld.pid \
    --log-error=$P/error.log
```

If it does't start, check $P/error.log why

Comment: you're saying the instance is crashing. I wonder how backup was taken and how do you know it's crashing

Comment: Thank you I will try that. I know the current instance was crashing because the website went down with DB error and mysqld restart failed. After I `kill -9` mysqld it did start again. What you are chainging is mainly to remove `--console` and `--innodb_force_recovery`, right? Changing log path and tmp probably does not hurt I guess.

Comment: right, you don't need --console as long as you logging to a file. innodb_force_recovery has its use but not applicable in your case. The major problem was a socket potentially at the same destination as for the main instance and you chown-ed tmp directory, not $P